Using different fonts in Incisor?
I am building a javascript game with Incisor. I have a particular font that I would like to use. What is the process for doing this with Incisor?
I have a .ttf file but I don't know what to do with it. What is my next step?

To add font definitions to your project, simply include .ttf or .otf files inside your project's Assets directory.
If you prefer to use images instead of font files, add a grouping of pngs with each file ending in _CharX, where the X is a number corresponding to the unicode decimal value of the character.
For example; the unicode decimal value of the capital letter A is 65.
If your font is named MyCoolFont, you should include a file named MyCoolFont_Char65.png to represent the capital letter A
Please note, you must include _Char0 in order for the image font to be recognized.
